# Using while loop to overwrite Arraylist values

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a cursor that returns 5 values from a query. I want to overwrite the 5 existing arraylist values with the results from the db query. In my code below the while loop is only overwriting the first `Arraylist` value.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
List<String> distancearray = new ArrayList<String>();
distancearray.add("0");
distancearray.add("0");
distancearray.add("0");
distancearray.add("0");
distancearray.add("0");

while(DistanceArray.moveToNext()){
    String uname = DistanceArray.getString(DistanceArray.getColumnIndex("distance"));
    int i = 0;
    distancearray.set(i, uname);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting `i` to 0 in each iteration of the while loop.

Move

```
int i = 0;
```

to before the loop

```
int i = 0;
while(DistanceArray.moveToNext()){
    String uname = DistanceArray.getString(DistanceArray.getColumnIndex("distance"));
    distancearray.set(i, uname);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing `i` to 0 on each iteration. You should move its declaration to outside the loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (DistanceArray.moveToNext()) {
    String uname = DistanceArray.getString(DistanceArray.getColumnIndex("distance"));
    distancearray.set(i, uname);
    i++;
}
```

I advise you to have checks on `i` in order to avoid out-of-bounds problems. Also please use the debugger in the future, it'll really help you better understanding your code flow and problems.